# How to study in a closed office environment?

Tags: job-search, work-environment, motivation

My new workplace is totally a closed environment, its a banking firm hence I am not even allowed to open personal mail. Github and Stackoverflow is allowed but I cannot log in, neither I can use any gist to take notes.

I am not happy with the opportunity hence I want to keep practicing for new job like Google or some product based company.

What should be my strategy to study without letting anyone know?

**Update 1:**

For people who are taking me wrongly, I was previously consultant in Google and as we all know the company culture is quite good, we were allowed to watch youtube videos and do everything we want. Now, I am from a poor family background and I had to join this banking firm where they are too restrictive(may be because of trading information and all) and since I have joined recently I can't event think to open youtube and I think 90% of the sites are blocked here. I have never seen in two weeks people ever on youtube or some online video content.

My job timing is also very constrained and unlike Google I am expected to do proper 9hrs of shift.

For people who are thinking I am cheating my company is false, I am here as a consultant and would have been more than happy to be a full time worker but things are never different. Anyways I am committed to give 100% but I cannot do straight 9 hours of coding, at least I can take 1 hour for myself.

Hope I am clear now.

Comment: Study on your non-working times. The time you are paid to work, you should be working, shouldn't you? If the restrictions in the environment are not good for you, you can always quit.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Many online resources do not require logging in, can you clarify what you are asking here? Are you asking how to do other work on company time?

Comment: Oh please, people! Don't downvote the question because you don't agree with what the OP wants to do. This is a useful question to a lot of people who contemplate doing the same.

Comment: How restricted are you during break time, and time between arriving at work and it being time to actually start work? The comments and answer cover actual working time, but not studying during in-office non-working time.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan there is no restriction as such apart from work station. If I am at my desk I cannot open anything else. There must be some strategy, like doing revision on paper note or using my phone etc.?

Comment: If you have down-time in your 9 hour shift, why not let your boss know that you want additional tasks. Then try to push for tasks that would require you to study something that you are already interested in. Then you wouldn't have to keep anything a secret.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> What should be my strategy to study without letting anyone know?

Study on your own time, at home, using your own equipment.
And don't tell anyone that you are studying if you don't want to let anyone know.

At work, do the work you are paid to do and avoid personal mail as directed. You aren't being paid to study or practice for a new job.

And if that doesn't work, you should quit and then you'll have plenty of time to study and practice for new jobs on your own time.